# Grouping all the laravel application routes using dynamic prefix

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.5

We have multiple client portal each one has a unique url like

- xyz.com/ClientPotal123
- xyz.com/ClientPotal234
- xyz.com/ClientPotalXXX

We will be routing all these url's to

> /var/www/html/Laravelapp/public

Laravelapp is our codebase which we use for all the clients.

Since ClientPotalXXX is dynamic and unique for all the clients, I need to get the value of ClientPotalXXX for loading client specific settings like url generation, database connection (We have different database for each client).

To achieve above I've done below changes..

My **Web.php** file is as below..

```
Route::pattern('ClientPortal','^ClientPortal([0-9]+)?');
Route::prefix('/{ClientPortal}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user/list', 'UserController@list')->name('list');
    Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@edit');
});
```

I've created **Middleware** with below code written in it..

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $database_name = strtolower($request->ClientPortal).'_db';
    config(['database.connections.mysql.database'=>$database_name]);
    config(['app_settings.client'=>$request->ClientPortal]);
    return $next($request);
}
```

And it's working fine but previously I used to access **$id** in **edit** function directly

```
public function edit($id){
    echo $id; // 12
}
```

But now $id return the value of ClientPortalXX everytime.

If I access id from Request it works fine

```
public function edit(Request $request){
    $id = $request->id; // 12
}
```

This is happening with all of the other routes where I'm using route parameters.

So I'm not sure if this happened because I'm using dynamic prefix for grouping all the routes? 
And now for every **route()** method which I've used in blade files for url generation I have to pass the second parameter ie. Value of {ClientPortal}

```
{{route('register',['ClientPortal'=>config('app_settings.client')])}}
```

Is this right implementation? I know we can make any varibale accessible globally using service provider but will it be right to do so?

My Laravel Version is 5.5.xx.. I'm just a beginner so any Help/Suggestion/Advice will be appreciated Thanks :)

**Update:**
 Nikola Gavric and Oluwafemi Sule had already clarified my doubt in comments below.

But since the group prefix is dynamic, How do I handle the route naming case? 
If I had to generate user list url using list route name which is mentioned in above web.php file.

Now I've to change this line..

```
 {{ route('list') }}
```

To

```
 {{ route('list',['ClientPortal'=> 'ClientPortalXXX' ]) }}
```

Since prefix is also a route param. 
Is this feasible option? Because I've to do this change everywhere where I've used route method for url generation.

Comment: How are you authenticating them when accessing for example `http://your-app.dev/clients/nikolag/books`?

Comment: How is it relevant to my question? But anyway for login process we use laravel's internal controllers/models which we generate using artisan command make:auth and as far as request authentication is concerned we check for user's session in middleware.

Comment: try `public function edit($clientportal, $id){}` and tell me what is the variable `$id` then

Comment: $ClientPortal value is portalname that is prefix{ClientPortal} and $id is user's id.

Comment: @Vishal Between now and when `$id` was `$id` what changed.

AFAIK, route prefix that are parameters are passed to the controller method or closure as well as @NikolaGavric pointed out.

Comment: Laravel seems to append your `generic route param` which is in this case `/{ClientPortal}` to your request so it ends up something like this `/{ClientPortal}/user/edit/{id}` and that url has 2 parameters instead of 1, so your `edit` function has to have 2 input parameters, besides `Request`, where first one is name of client portal and second is id, does this clarify why your `id` was returning the name of the portal?

Comment: Thanks a lot @NikolaGavric and Oluwafemi Sule. Honestly I didn't knew that group prefix as also treated as route param as I said I'm just a beginner

Comment: Not a problem, glad you fixed it :)

Comment: @NikolaGavric I've many such methods so how do I handle this situation.. I can't be passing ClientPortal to each and every method.. Should I have to access the route param's using Request class instead?

Comment: The thing is that in order for you to know which `Client` is trying to access your resources, you need that input, so if you remove `ClientPortal` then you won't know which database, url generation and other settings to use, I'm still not sure what your **goal** is, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hmmmm you just answered your own question  "Just to identify the ClientPortalXXX so that we can change the database and other client specific settings accordingly". Using middleware I can change those right?  Because I'm able to get ClientPotalXX in middleware.